# Unexpected '{' when defining a function with 2 variables in R

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to define a Cohen's D function, but I get the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:20: unexpected '{'
1: cohens_d <- f(x, y){
                       ^
```

The code I wrote is:

```
cohens_d <- f(x, y){
    lx <- length(x)-1
    ly <- length(y)-1
    md <- (mean(x)-mean(y))
    sigma <- sqrt((lx * var(x)+ ly * var(y))/(lx + ly))
    cd <- md/sigma
    return(cd)
}
```

I get a similar error even with simple functions like the one here:

```
add <- f(x, y) {
    return(x+y)
}
```

Comment: What is `f`? Do you mean `cohens_d <- function(x, y) {`? (Your function defines fine when that change is made, I think this is just a typo.)

Comment: `cohens_d <- f(x, y)....`should have been `cohens_d <- function(x, y)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "f" instead of "function", try:

```
cohens_d <- function(x, y){
  lx <- length(x)-1
  ly <- length(y)-1
  md <- (mean(x)-mean(y))
  sigma <- sqrt((lx * var(x)+ ly * var(y))/(lx + ly))
  cd <- md/sigma
  return(cd)
}
```